# Grep all status apart from "200" from curl output

Tags: shell, curl, grep

Shell script of mine has "n" number of curl commands and whose output would be displayed as below :

"n" number of status would be displayed based on my "for loop".

From this output i want to grep all the status apart from "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and then writing it to a file. Pls help me. I am stuck.

```
upload completely sent off: 74 out of 74 bytes
 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 Content-Security-Policy: 
 Content-Type: text/plain

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
 Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: so your desired output would be just the first "block" of messages? Good luck.

Comment: yes, i would like to capture only the the line like this "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" and not "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: your best bet is to specifically include the output you expect. Right now I can't tell if you want 1 line of output or 3. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract those "blocks" which don't contain `200 Status`, grep is not the right tool, since it does line based matching.

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -v RS="" '!/ 200 OK/ input> output
```

If you just want to grab those status lines,E.g. `HTTP/1.1 500 Inter....` you can try :

```
grep -P 'HTTP/1\.1(?!\s*200 OK)' input
```